# I want to use xib file into by uitableview cell storyboard

Tags: objective-c

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    SectionHeaderView *sectionHeaderView = [self.tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:SectionHeaderViewIdentifier];

    Category *sectionInfo = (self.sectionInfoArray)[section];
       sectionHeaderView.categoryLabel.text = sectionInfo.categoryName;
    NSLog(@"header section: %@", sectionInfo.categoryName);

    sectionHeaderView.section = section;
    sectionHeaderView.delegate = self;

    return sectionHeaderView;

 }
```

Note:
`Category` is my model class which also contains my networking to webservice

`SectionHeaderView` is my xib view which contains `UILabel` named: `categoryLabel`.

I wanna display my data into the UILabel field in xib view and display in header section of the UITableviewCell.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSObject 0x14ee9d50> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view.'
*** First throw call stack:
```

Comment: Did you set the correct class of the various object (the Reuse View) to SectionHeaderView in your Xib ?

Comment: yes, I can display my categoryName data to textlabel of uitableview cell but If i want same data to shown with uilabel connected to uitableviewcell class, than i get above error. is it because I am directly displaying the categoryname from the model class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code...

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    SectionHeaderView *sectionHeaderView = (SectionHeaderView *) [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed: @"SectionHeaderView" owner:self options:nil]    firstObject];

    Category *sectionInfo = (self.sectionInfoArray)[section];
    sectionHeaderView.categoryLabel.text = sectionInfo.categoryName;
    NSLog(@"header section: %@", sectionInfo.categoryName);

    sectionHeaderView.section = section;
    sectionHeaderView.delegate = self;

    return sectionHeaderView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You did't provide the enough information of how u are initilising the header view in the custom `SectionHeaderView`, any way i will give the example how u can crate the custom header view using custom view and xib file,

first u need to subclass the `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`, lets say name it as `SectionHeaderView`.

in xib, make sure to set `UIView` class to  `SectionHeaderView`. then only u can able to create  outlet's for UI elements.

in `SectionHeaderView.h`,

```
@interface SectionHeaderView : UITableViewHeaderFooterView
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *categoryLabel;
@end
```

and in `SectionHeaderView.m`

```
#import "SectionHeaderView.h"

@implementation SectionHeaderView

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
   //do things after nib is loaded
   [super awakeFromNib];

}

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
  [super layoutSubviews];
  //set frames hear
}

@end
```

and in `ViewController.m`, just register the xib file that u are going to use

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
   [self.aTableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"SectionHeaderView" bundle:nil] forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier:@"HEADER_REUSE_ID"];
}
```

and in the method,

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   SectionHeaderView *view =   [tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:@"HEADER_REUSE_ID"];
   view.categoryLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"section:%ld",(long)section];
   return view;
}
```